# Negative disk used space after shrinking RAID1 in Debian 11

Tags: debian, hard-disk, raid, mdadm, resize2fs

I resized an ext4 software RAID1 consisting of two disks sda3 and sdb3 (in rescue mode, i.e. disks are not mounted):

```
e2fsck -f /dev/md126
resize2fs /dev/md126 39G
mdadm --grow /dev/md126 --size 40G

mdadm /dev/md126 --fail /dev/sda3
mdadm /dev/md126 --remove /dev/sda3
parted /dev/sda
   (parted) print
   Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system     Flags
   1      1049kB  537MB   536MB   primary  linux-swap(v1)
   2      537MB   1166MB  629MB   primary                  boot, raid
   3      1166MB  1024GB  1023GB  primary                  raid
   (parted) resizepart
   Partition number? 3
   End? 48GB
mdadm /dev/md126 --add /dev/sda3
```

Then the same procedure for sdb3.

The RAID successfully rebuilds and I am able to boot in the normal mode.

However, now I am getting negative used space:

```
root@server:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md126       23G  -13G   34G    - /mnt/md126
```

Digging deeper:

```
root@server:~# tune2fs -l /dev/md126
Filesystem state:         clean
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Block count:              10223616
Reserved block count:     511180
Overhead blocks:          4201607
Free blocks:              9411982
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1024
Blocks per group:         32768
```

It seems the culprit is the "Overhead blocks" which did not change after resizing the RAID (it is still the same number). Originally the size of sda3 and sdb3 partitions was 952.8G

Am I correct that the "negative" disk usage is caused by the "Overhead blocks"?
Secondly, is there any way to reduce these blocks and thus eliminate the negative "Used" disk space?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command with the file system unmounted:

```
debugfs -w -R "set_super_value overhead_blocks 0" /dev/sdXX
```

Then the next time you mount the file system, the correct value for "Overhead blocks" will get recalculated and filled in.

After that, the correct amount of diskspace will be available again.